# Embedding youtube with iframe in Android 4.1.2

Tags: android, html, cordova

i'm developing an Html5+jquery mobile+ phonegap app...i'm tring to embed a youtube/vimeo video using the iframe...vimeo works great on iOS device but none on Android...
i'm testing on Galaxy S2 with Android 4.1.2...the code for embed is:

```
<iframe width="100%" height="182px" src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/VtOWCTgJbmU&amp;vq=large"  frameborder="0" allowfullscreen style="color:transparent; height:182px; position:absolute;"></iframe>
```

the problem is that the video quality is very poor...the thumbnail has the width and height in the code and the quality is ok...but when the video starts it becomes small and the quality is poor...

i can't understand if this player is the html5 or what else...
any idea for the resolution?!?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Rather than going for an iframe, you can try this video plugin which works on Anddroid:

http://simonmacdonald.blogspot.in/2011/11/video-player-plugin-for-phonegap.html

Best Luck!

Comment: Hi,i'm trying to use this plugin...i follow the steps in the developer page...but i have 2 problems...
1- i haven't the phonegap.js but i have cordova-2.5.0.js
2- i add the <plugin name="VideoPlayer" value="com.phonegap.plugins.video.VideoPlayer" /> in the res/xml/config.xml instead of res/xml/plugins.xml...i read it's ok but i recive this error: The markup in the document following the root element must be well-formed.
help ;)